# regex to find a value from a string in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a json like this

```
{
  "foregroundDark": "##FF1F6D",
  "foregroundLight": "##F4FF80",
  "background": "##3029FF",
  "background2": "#FFFFFF",
  "barFontColors": ".cmtyx_color_1 { background-color:#FFBF36 !important; }.cmtyx_border_color_1 { border-color: #FFBF36 !important; }.cmtyx_text_color_1 { color: #FFBF36 !important; }.cmtyx_color_2 { background-color:#40EFFF !important; }.cmtyx_border_color_2 { border-color: #40EFFF !important; } .cmtyx_text_color_2 { color: #40EFFF !important; } .cmtyx_color_3 { background-color:#52FF42 !important; }.cmtyx_border_color_3 { border-color: #52FF42 !important; }.cmtyx_text_color_3 { color: #52FF42 !important; }.cmtyx_color_4 { background-color:#3DAEFF !important; }.cmtyx_border_color_4 { border-color: #3DAEFF !important; }.cmtyx_text_color_4 { color: #3DAEFF !important; }"
}
```

from this  json you can find a key `barFontColors`.I need value of color of all these classes `.cmtyx_text_color_1`,`.cmtyx_text_color_2`,`.cmtyx_text_color_3`, `.cmtyx_text_color_4`. only value  without `!important` also. thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it possible you can change the response? It would make *far* more sense to have the colours passed as string in an array. As it stands right now you're going to have to dissect that string using Regex, which isn't going to be pretty, or very rigid code.

Comment: Quite easy even without parsing. Hint: use browser parser for this.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan It's a third party response so I can't change.

Comment: @dfsq No dear i need to parse for my ui. it's a dynamic response.

Comment: I understand the question. I'm saying you can do it quite easily without parsing anything. DOMParser can be used for this. Create fake document, append stylesheet, read stylesheet.rules, etc. Or create dirty regexes and parse, also an option.

Comment: Maybe you're looking for something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/njjyj6u6/ Be sure to open your browser console to view the results. If you don't want/need to know the class then you can remove `classN`. I have only added that for debugging.

Comment: @NewToJS Thanks a lot. You save my day.

Comment: @PradyutManna You are very welcome.

Answer (score 0):

To get the elements from that unjasoned string, let's transform that string to something that can be parsed to a javascript object.

After that's done you can just access it's elements from the object.

```js
var myObj = {
  "foregroundDark": "##FF1F6D",
  "foregroundLight": "##F4FF80",
  "background": "##3029FF",
  "background2": "#FFFFFF",
  "barFontColors": ".cmtyx_color_1 { background-color:#FFBF36 !important; }.cmtyx_border_color_1 { border-color: #FFBF36 !important; }.cmtyx_text_color_1 { color: #FFBF36 !important; }.cmtyx_color_2 { background-color:#40EFFF !important; }.cmtyx_border_color_2 { border-color: #40EFFF !important; } .cmtyx_text_color_2 { color: #40EFFF !important; } .cmtyx_color_3 { background-color:#52FF42 !important; }.cmtyx_border_color_3 { border-color: #52FF42 !important; }.cmtyx_text_color_3 { color: #52FF42 }.cmtyx_color_4 { background-color:#3DAEFF !important; }.cmtyx_border_color_4 { border-color: #3DAEFF !important; }.cmtyx_text_color_4 { color: #3DAEFF !important; }"
};


var tmpBarFontColors = '{'+ myObj.barFontColors.replace(/-/g,'_') +'}';
tmpBarFontColors = tmpBarFontColors.replace(/\.(\w+)\s*\{\s*(\w+)\s*:\s*([#\w]+)\s*([!\w]+)?[^}]*\}/g, '"$1":{"$2":"$3","flag":"$4"}');
tmpBarFontColors = tmpBarFontColors.replace(/\}\s*"/g,'}, "');

myObj.barFontColors = JSON.parse( tmpBarFontColors );

//console.log(tmpBarFontColors );
console.log("cmtyx color 1 is " + myObj.barFontColors.cmtyx_color_1.background_color);
console.log(myObj.barFontColors);
```